# Enabling RabbitMQ management Plugin Failed

Tags: rabbitmq

In Centos 7 , I had Installed RabbitMQ using the Following Erlang and RabbitMQ RPM File's

**erlang-18.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm**

**rabbitmq-server-3.6.9-1.el7.noarch.rpm**

I can able start the RabbitMQ

But Management Plugin Fail's with the Error

**Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@f70c87670946... failed.**

**Error: noproc**

Answer (score 2):

Now Able to enable Plugin I had tried immediately after RabbitMQ start's, So its failed

Try after 60 s after RabbitMQ start's